# How to set filename property in BlobStore (Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rename, blobstore

It is possible to rename a file stored in Blobstore? but if this is not possible, how could clone a saved file with another filename?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blobstore entities are immutable - once created, they cannot be changed.

You would need to create a new entity and copy the data. Since [programmatic access to Blobstore has been deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore), you should [save blobs to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) and then [access them via Blobstore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage): when saving data to Cloud Storage, save the key you get and simply use it with Blobstorage APIs.

Comment: Thanks peter, has been very helpful. I have chosen to manage the filenames a Map <BlobKey ID, filename> in memcache.

Thank You.